# Client Server on Sockets with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

My goal is to write a desktop client server application running on a local network. There will be a database on the server. I want to use `Hibernate` to work with the database.
For example, I can have many tables in the database, like `Student`, `Teacher`, and so on.

```
@Entity
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private int age;
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Teacher {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String schoolName;

    @Column
    private String subject;
}
```

Can you give me some advice on how best to do this: when the client sends some query

```
while ((operation = in.readLine()) != null) {
    switch (operation) {
        case "GET_ALL":
            break;
        case "GET_BY_ID":
            break;
        case "ADD":
            break;
        case "UPDATE":
            break;
        case "DELETE":
            break;
}
```

Then I need to understand which table and which class of object this refers to? For example, if I want to update a table, then my idea is that a client will send the object to be replaced.

```
Object recievedObject = objectInputStream.readObject();
```

```
// and use this method
public void update(T entity) {
    try(Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {
        session.update(entity);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

But the problem is, how do I determine which class this object belongs to? It can be a `Teacher` or `Student` class or any other class. Of course, I can use `if` and check for class Type, but this approach is not very good if there are a lot of database entities.

```
if (recievedObject instanceof Student) {
    // do something
}
```

I was thinking about using `polymorphism` so that all entity classes inherit from some class. But I am at a loss how to implement this correctly. Can you give me advice on how to solve my problem or show me a short example? I would be grateful. And more: should I use the `DAO` package?

Comment: Your `update` method appears to work for any entity.